# JarSigner Class not found exception

Tags: java, jar, java-web-start, jnlp, jarsigner

I'm trying sign jar for distribution of my java project via JWS, what i have done is

1. I have packed my class files into a jar
2. created password using keytool - keytool -genkey -keystore xxx -alias xxx
3. sign jar using jarsigner -keystore xxx Test.jar xxx -  command

but the error I've got is No class found exception . Sun.security.tools.jarsigner.

I'm using JDk 1.6.0.21.
I tried unpacking Tools.jar and could find the jarsigner class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running 'java' from the JRE not the JDK. The JRE doesn't contain the 'jarsigner' tool.